# How to fix the URI does not specify a valid host name in ClientProtocolException:

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

When I execute the elastic search java API using jest client, I face the following error

> org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException: URI does not specify a valid host name:localhost:9200/index/type/_search

I tries various possibilities to fix this error, but I am stuck. How can I fix this?

Comment: You're probably just missing `http://` at the beginning but can you show a bit more of the code where you create the Jest client?

Comment: yes unfortunately i missed it  after i use http:// it works fine.thanks for ur response.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You just need to add `http://` at the beginning of the URI.

Answer (score -1):

If you are seeing the same error in JMeter while you want to use a response Json key value in another variable(by creating a new HTTP Request) then use JSON Extractor instead of Regular Expression extractor. Thread Group->Right click and Add->Post Processor->JSON Extractor)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF0l5.png)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.